# Thunderbird: Search to, cc and from in one step

Tags: thunderbird, search

I can search for "to", "to,cc" and "from" with the thunderbird search dialog.

But how can I search for to, cc and from in one step?

Strange but true, the search dialog of local folders has a field "from, to, cc or bcc". The search dialog for IMAP folders is missing a way to search for incomming and outgoing message of an email address.

**Update**
If I search on the IMAP server, then I don't have the "from, to, cc or bcc" choice. If I select the local search, then I have it.

Any way to enable it for server side search?

Answer (score 4):

You can right click on a folder, click on "search messages" to open following dialog.

Then, just select "From, to, CC or bcc"... "contains"... and insert the e-mail address.

Maybe you have to enable "Keep messages for this account on this computer".

[image: Thunderbird search dialog]
[image: Thunderbird account settings]

Comment: Would you mind taking the screenshot again, starting thunderbird with `LC_ALL=C thunderbird`, so as to get English output instead of German?

Comment: Good idea, will also help me for future screenshots, thanks :)

Comment: My drop down box does not contain the field "From, To, CC, ...". If it would, I would not have asked the question. I use Thunderbird version 31.6.0. How can this be?

Comment: @guettli, i've it in version 31.7.0

Comment: @Sneetsher I updated the question and updated my thunderbird to 31.7.0. The option is missing only if I use server side search (which I prefer).

Comment: I have updated my answer.